# property layer not found on object of type UIBarButtonitem

Tags: ios

I am trying to apply this animation to a UIBarButtonItem:

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    theAnimation.duration=1.0;
    theAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
    theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
    [plusbutton.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

but I get the error reported in the title on the last line of code. How can I access the layer of a barbuttonItem?

Answer (score 6):

A bar button item isn't a view, and it doesn't have a layer.

Assuming you're not trying this on a system item, access the layer of the item's `customView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the QuartCore framework, and import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h into your class to work with layers.

Comment: While this may be true, it's not the problem here.